# Extracting plain integer from a bigNumber

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I have the requirement to extract plain integer from a smart contract function that returns a bigNumber. I'm trying to extract as seen below. Is this a good practice or a bad workaround? If its the latter, can someone suggest a better way of doing this?

`const bal = parseInt(formatUnits(balance,"wei"));`

Comment: try this: `ethers.utils.formatEther(BIGNUMBER)`

Comment: Thanks for replying @AhmadGorji. formatEther returns a hex number with 17 preceding zeros. As a result I'm not able able to use it as integer for normal arithmetic

Comment: Are you sure?! It returns in ether in string for me! Then you can change it into wei by `* 10**18`! Also I should note that there is no "bad workaround"! If it works OK for you that is enough!

Comment: Also you can change BigNumber into number by `Number(RESULT)`